# How can I change the MAC address on my Android device?

Tags: android

Is there a simple way to manually change the MAC address of an Android device, such as from a text field in some settings panel or in a text file I can edit?

Can this be done programmatically? For example, is there an Android library I could call from within my code to change the MAC address?

Can we apply the same changes to the Bluetooth adapter just as we can with the WiFi adapter?

Comment: You want code? have you tried any code?

Comment: Till now I had only get the MAC address of the device but for changing it I could not find any thing.

Comment: Code or any Idea by which it is possible  then please tell me..

Answer (score 3):

you should check this links.

1. [Change WiFi MAC Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287790/change-wifi-mac-address)
2. [Get MAC Address of android device without Wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191832/get-mac-address-of-android-device-without-wifi)
3. [How to change (permanent) MAC ADDRESS on my android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17657/how-to-change-permanent-mac-address-on-my-android-phone)