# Changing MAC Address in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to change the Mac address of my rooted Note 2 android device.

I did the following:

- busybox ifconfig wlan0 down
- busybox ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:55
- busybox ifconfig wlan0 up

The Mac address does get changed but subsequently I can't connect to my router as it is showing authentication failure.

Any idea what's wrong? Is there any other way to change the Mac address in Android?

Comment: What exactly did you expect to happen? You changed your mac address, so now your device appears alien to your router, and your router is properly rejecting it. Mac address is the ONLY way your router has to identify your device on the network, and now you've changed the address.

Comment: @MarcB - wifi security is **not** accomplished by MAC address, but by higher level data a bit less trivial to spoof.  It's true that changing the MAC address might invalidate that, but the fix would be to re-authenticate.

Comment: @MarcB Shouldn't the router detect it as a new device? Since it is now using a new mac address?

Comment: @chris: yes, but if the router's got mac address filtering on, then the router is going to reject that MAC, no matter what the WPA/WPA2 stuff is saying.

Comment: @MarcB I tried with 2 routers, both do not have mac address filtering. In both cases, i could not join the network. Have the same authentication failed issue.

Comment: As a test, what if you set up one of your routers with no security (and no upstream connection to anything) and try to connect to that?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, if the router have no security, it could connect without any issues. But if WPA2 is on, it doesn't connects and shows authentication error. Any idea what's the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**use this:**

you need to use adb shell and su in terminal.

(i change wlan0) you can see all by this command "ip link show"

```
adb shell
su
ip link show wlan0
ifconfig wlan0 down;
ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 12:13:15:16:18:19  
ifconfig wlan0 up;
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to change wifi mac address of rooted deviced 
I advise you to use wifi mac changer

And fill a mac and click hard change 
Because I've tried terminal emu but no way 
Good luck

Comment: Could you please [disclose the author's affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)?