# programmatically change Mac address-Android

Tags: java, android, linux, mac-address

I'm writing a program to spoof the mac address of a device. So far I was able to get root access by running the command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

Now I want to run commands by doing:

```
for (String currCommand : commands)
{
    os.writeBytes(currCommand + "\n");
    os.flush();
}
```

but I'm not sure which commands will do this for me? Does anyone know the commands to run to get into the mac address and modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this link http://www.gohacking.com/spoof-mac-address-on-android-phones/ the phone must be rooted and busybox must be installed.

After entering `su` the commands are:

```
# show the actual mac address
busybox iplink show eth0
# change the mac adress 
busybox ifconfig eth0 hw ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way

use ADB shell and ifconfig

```
adb shell
su
ip link show wlan0
ifconfig wlan0 down;
ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 12:13:15:16:18:19  
ifconfig wlan0 up;
```

check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/63251530/4797289